# Graphs of interesting integrals of the form: $\int \sin^a(x^a)\cos^a(x^a)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, graphing-functions

*Here are a few graphs of the form:-* $$\int \sin^a(x^a)\cos^a(x^a)dx$$
Where $a$ is an even, positive integer.

---

**$a = 2$**

[image]

---

**$a = 4$**

[image]

---

**$a = 6$**

[image]

---

---

*Now, a few graphs of the form:-* $$\int \sin^a(x^a)\cos^a(x^a)dx$$
Where $a$ is an odd, positive integer.

---

**$a = 1$** (Common)

[image]

---

**$a = 3$**

[image]

---

**$a = 5$**

[image]

---

**$a = 7$**

[image]

---

---

The integrals themselves are hideous.. But the graphs are fun to observe (At least for me), especially for the cases where a is odd.

I know that the difference in these graphs (Between odd and even $a$ ) is caused mainly by the powers the sin and cos functions are raised to, rather than the powers of the arguments of these functions.

I have 4 questions :-

1. **Why does $\int \sin^a(x^a)\cos^a(x^a)dx$ , where $a$ is even, have fewer and fewer oscillations (i.e. the line becomes less wavy) as the value of $a$ increases?** *(Note: I know that the lines come closer and closer to the x-axis as evidenced by the outputs of the integral on the graph)*
2. *What is going on when $a$ is odd? Can you explain why that beaker-like structure is formed; specifically,* **why does it seems to dip around a certain value ,then raise again to oscillate so much and the die out?**
3. Some questions regarding an observation of the case $a = 5$: **Why does there seem to be a tiny bump just after the '4' on the x-axis? What value could be causing this, and why?**
4. **And when $a = 7$, why do there seem to be tiny successive bumps beyond 2 and -2?**

---

*I realize that answers may not exist for all of these questions, because these maybe the intrinsic qualities of the graph of the integral in discussion, but I'm hoping that some people may have insights and explanations for the features of the graphs I've questioned about....* ***Especially questions 3 and 4.*** I hope you don't consider the question silly; I'm genuinely interested in knowing the reasons (If they exist) for the above graphs.

Comment: What are the limits of integration?  How are you computing the antiderivatives?

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, I didn't compute it myself; I got it off Wolfram Alpha while searching for similar anti derivatives.

Comment: So, what is the lower limit in WA's algorithm.  In order to produce the graphs, there must be some assumption.

Comment: Well...it differs from graph to graph; for example: $a=5$, WA has been plotted it from-4.1 to 4.9

Comment: Does that mean the lower limit is $-4.1$ and the upper limit is $x$?

Comment: I suggest plotting the integrands and investigate their behaviors.  These will be the derivative functions of the functions that you have plotted herein.

Comment: @Dr.MV I'm in the process of doing that... and for the x-values plotted, the lower limit is -4.1, and upper limit is 4.9 (Of course, it extends further down either side, but the graph shows it between these values)

Comment: The bumps are likely due to resolution issues.  These are numerical integrals of highly oscillatory functions.  Numerical approximations might be extending beyond their usefulness

Comment: Could you conform by using Mathematica to zoom into the graphs? I'm not a Wolfram Alpha pro user, so I can't do that..

Comment: I meant confirm

Comment: Since $\sin 2 x = 2 \sin x \cos x$, you can simplify your integrand by writing it as $2^{-a} \sin^a(2 x^a)$. That being so, it would be reasonable to normalize by removing the vertical and horizontal scale factors; that is, concentrate on $\sin^a(x^a)$. The simpler the functions, the smaller the risk of computational error and graphical anomalies and such.